# Adding Fields to DataTable in ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net

Users are uploading an Excel file to my site which I'm then going to write to the database. I'd like to add two additional columns (Email and TimeStamp). I'm not getting any specific error. Any suggestions on how to remedy? Code below:

```
public static class ExcelPackageExtensions
{
    public static DataTable ToDataTable(this ExcelPackage package)
    {
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Email");
        dt.Columns.Add("TimeStamp");
        foreach (var firstRowCell in worksheet.Cells[1,1,1,worksheet.Dimension.End.Column])
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(firstRowCell.Text);
        }
        for (var rownumber=2; rownumber <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; rownumber++)
        {
            var row = worksheet.Cells[rownumber, 1, rownumber, worksheet.Dimension.End.Column];
            var newrow = dt.NewRow();
            newrow["Email"] = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
            newrow["TimeStamp"] = DateTime.Now;
            foreach (var cell in row)
            {
                newrow[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Text;
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(newrow);
        }
        return dt;
    }
}
```

Comment: How to remedy what? You haven't stated a problem.

Comment: You are probably going to have to debug your code. When I remove all the superfluous stuff about the spreadsheet parsing it works just fine (see https://dotnetfiddle.net/tUTKIV). Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.